# Как грамотно осуществить Route по городам?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Проект `net core mvc 3.0`. Оптимизируем сайт под `seo` и т.д. Решено сделать `route` следующим образом `https://домен.ru/название города/`.В базе, в таблице `city` - поля `id` - `primary key` и `name varchar(255)`, а в таблице товары-есть внешний ключ `city_id`, ссылающийся на `id` города. Как грамотнее работать с базой `EF Core` в данном случае,вешать `btree` индекс на поле `name` и при `route`, указанном выше при выборке товаров делать `join city`, а затем сравнивать значение в параметре запроса с полем `name`? Или дергать с параметра запроса название города, делать выборку в таблице `city` на соответствие name и доставать `id`, а затем делать выборку у товаров `where city_id` равно этому `id`?

Comment: Один запрос всяко быстрее двух. Да и по коду проще.

Comment: `https://домен.ru/название города/` - а что будет если в БД попадут 2 города с одинаковым названием ? Я так понимаю, что может быт ьи не только города (беру населенные пункты). Так же учтите колличество возможных данных...если их не много, то по сути, что 2, что 10 запросов.